# How to make radio button with mysql value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I want to make radiobutton with mysql

MY CODE

[image: code]

But it isn't make sense (SERVER ERROR:500)
Beacause of html form tag!
So I want to ask you!
"How can I make radiobutton with mysql value?"

Comment: please paste your code here so that I can correct it.

Comment: @Park, that's not `mysql` doing that `job` it's PHP. Your trying to display html form inside a loop but your missing something crucial part. Can you provide your codes here and am sure guys are willing to help you.

Comment: btw: if you make extract($row) you don't have to do N assignments (1 for each desired key)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: You should paste the actual code text into the question and not an image of the code. Use the [edit] button to update the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but I think I know what you mean. You want to create a radio button giving it a value from your database.

You don't create a form for each radio button. Instead, create the radio buttons within a single form tag.

Something like this:

```
echo "<form name='' action='index.php' method='post'>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 echo "<input type='radio' name='" .$q . "' value='".$q ."'>" .$q . "<br />";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='" .$a1 . "' value='".$a1 ."'>" .$a1 . "<br />";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='" .$a2 . "' value='".$a2 ."'>" .$a2 . "<br />";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='" .$a3 . "' value='".$a3 ."'>" .$a3 . "<br />";
}

echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **echo** statement change the parameter **"** to **'**.
Try this it will be defiantly works.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

    $q = $row['q'];

    echo "<tr>
         <td>
            <form name='' action='index.php' method='post'>
                <input type='radio' name='q' value='".$q."'
            </form>
         </td>
          </tr>";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you properly able to establish a connection to the server? Just `var_dump` or `print_r` to see what you are getting from the database.

Comment: This is supposed to be comment!